# How to render a partial view from another project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm trying to render a partial view from another project.

It's very simple. I've highlighted the string where should be replace for the _View1 since the another one.

What do I need to add to the string to recognize and access to the razor partial view?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not supported in ASP.NET MVC per default.

You have to create a custom `VirtualPathProvider` which can locate your views. You also have to use `@inherit` instead of `@model`.

Or you can use my open source MvcContrib project as I describe here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-mvccontrib-the-plugin-system/

(the code is located at github + nuget: https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.mvccontrib)

Comment: In fact, I was starting reading about build your own provider implementation here. Can you tell a little bit of more about what do you men by 'You also have to use @inherit instead of @model.'? I'm not too experience in MVC and that confuse me

Comment: I haven't figure out why, but Razor do not recognize the `@model` directive in views which are not located in the main assembly. The  `@inherit` directive tells Razor which base class to use for the views (and the model). You can find more information about it at MSDN. However, if you use my library you can use `@model` like before. I take care of the transformation for you.

Comment: @jgauffin any resource how to to use EmbeddedViewFileProvider in mvc 5 ?